# How to find max value of column with NULL being included and considered the max

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table with a column of dates which includes dates and `NULL` values. I am trying to figure out a way to find the MAX `Date`, per `ID`, or if there is a `NULL` value, then to return `NULL` instead.

So for example:

```
ID    Date
1     2014-01-01
1     2014-02-01
1     2014-03-01
2     2014-02-01
2     NULL
3     NULL
4     2014-03-01
```

So what I am trying to yield is:

```
1 = 2014-03-01
2 = NULL
3 = NULL
4 = 2014-03-01
```

As of right now I am using something like this:

```
NULLIF(MAX(COALESCE(n.[SentDate], '12/16/9997')),'12/16/9997') AS [MaxSentDate]
```

I am 99% sure that no one will ever put in a date of `12/16/9997`, but I would like to come up with a proper solution rather than using a hackish one like this.

Comment: Wouldn't the max of 2 = `2014-02-01`?

Comment: Something like what you've come up is all I can think of.  I would be inclined to say that the requirement is forcing you into this 'hack'.

Comment: @Elias - No, basically if the ID contains a NULL value, the NULL will always come back instead of the date regardless of what the date is

Comment: To make it feel slightly less hackish, consider using the max datetime value `12/31/9999`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this :

```
SELECT [ID]
     , CASE WHEN MAX(CASE WHEN [Date] IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0 THEN MAX([Date]) END
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY [ID]
```

Comment: Thanks, looks like performance is pretty similar as well between the two with possibly a slight edge to the way I have it above. I will take the very slight performance decrease for the code reliability of your solution!

Comment: @mamesh did you check performance of all other solutions provided?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ID, [Date]
FROM (
      SELECT ID 
         ,[DATE]
         ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY CASE WHEN [Date] IS NULL 
                                                           THEN '99991212'
                                                           ELSE [Date] END DESC) RN               
      FROM TABLE_NAME) A
WHERE RN = 1
```

### [`Working SQL FIDDLE`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9b113/1)

Answer (score 1):

If you want null to be returned:

```
    SELECT id, max([date]) from #t t1
    WHERE not exists (select 1 from #t t2 where t2.date is null and t1.id = t2.id) 
    GROUP BY id
 UNION ALL
    SELECT id, NULL from #t t1 
    WHERE t1.date IS NULL  
    GROUP BY id ;
```

Comment: simplified the second part.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if there is a null in the group by using `COUNT(*) = COUNT([DATE])`(the right part returns `COUNT` for all values in the group, the left part return only nonnull values) :

```
SELECT [ID]
     , CASE WHEN COUNT(*) = COUNT([DATE]) THEN MAX([DATE]) ELSE NULL END AS [DATE] 
FROM [TEST_TABLE]
GROUP BY [ID]
```

[**Example**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9b113/4)

Comment: Have you tried this?  I don't think you can nest aggregate functions like that.

Comment: i don't see this `count(*)` vs `count(date)` behaviour on SQL Server 2008

Comment: @Andrew : Thank you, I have not noticed that, actually, while updating my answer.

Comment: @1_CR : Well, [I've checked it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms175997.aspx) before posting here

Comment: @ypercube : There was a nesting aggregate function after I've updated this line. Instead of moving MAX in the CASE I wrapped CASE with it and unfortunately have not noticed it.

Comment: @Notulysses Thnx, I see the edit, didn't notice before. Your answer is correct now.